# How to find and replace the string stored inside the char array?

Tags: c++, linux, shell

Guys I am using c++ to build a shell program, and here is the code I get the present username and working address, but I want to edit the address if it contains the root directory, the containing part will be replaced to "~", but I don't know how to do it..

I found an idea which is the way do shift left for the several bit of size of the pw_dir..But how to do it?

Please help me.

```
char hostname[32];
char present_addr[255];
struct passwd *getuser;

void default_output() {

getuser = getpwuid(getuid());
gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname));
getcwd(present_addr, sizeof(present_addr));

if (strcmp(present_addr, getuser->pw_dir) == 0) {
    cout << "[CYHshell]" << getuser->pw_name << "@" << hostname << ":" << "~$ ";
}
else
    cout << "[CYHshell]" << getuser->pw_name << "@" << hostname << ":" << present_addr << "$ ";
}
```

Well, the example should be like this:

/Users/howechen/Library/Caches/clion10/cmake/generated/374e429/374e429/Debug$

This is the current working directory of my program, and it should be fixed to

```
~/Library/Caches/clion10/cmake/generated/374e429/374e429/Debug$
```

cause

```
/Users/howechen/
```

is my root directory

Comment: Show us an example input and desired output.

Comment: Shifting is only for bits in bytes. Strings cannot be processed like this ( you need to use family of functions `str*`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a string variable to use its [replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) function.

You have to add an include:

```
#include <string>
```

And use a temp string variable:
    char hostname[32];
    char present_addr[255];
    struct passwd *getuser;

```
void default_output() {

getuser = getpwuid(getuid());
gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname));
getcwd(present_addr, sizeof(present_addr));

std::string outputString = present_addr;
outputString.replace(getuser->pw_dir, "~");
```

But you'll have to put the data back in present_addr:

```
for (unsigned int i=0; i<outputString.length(); i++)
{
    present_addr[i] = outputString.c_str()[i];
}
present_addr[i+1] = '\0';
```

or

```
memcpy(present_addr, outputString.c_str(), outputString.length());
```

I didn't put a security on present_addr[i], but it should be ok here.

Comment: Thank you very much, your code is useful and I fixed a problem: it should be outputString.replace(0,sizeof(getuser->pw_dir),"~",0,1);

Comment: But another question is I cannot get the correct size of pw_dir by using sizeof(), do you know why?

Comment: Yeah I have figured it out:

 string present_addr_fixed = present_addr;
    string root_directory=getuser->pw_dir;

    present_addr_fixed.replace(0,root_directory.length(),"~",0,1);

Thank you very much

Comment: pw_dir is a char*, sizeof will only return the size of the variable type. You can use strlen if you don't want to have an other string.